# find 3 adjacent digits in a string

Tags: regex

Here is one solution to find all groups of 3 adjacent digits in a string:

```
m=re.findall(r"(?:\A|\s)\d\d\d(?:\s|$)", "111 chgsds 123 jdswu 456 x111101 765")
```

The output after calling findall:

```
['111 ', ' 123 ', ' 456 ', ' 765']
```

but I'm looking for a more elegant solution. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by more elegant ? What's not elegant in the current solution !

Comment: @Sniffer I suppose it could use `\d{3}` instead of `\d\d\d`.

Comment: What would you use instead of (?:\A|\s) and (?:\s|$) ?

Comment: "all groups of 3 adjacent digits" would include 111 and 101.  This seems to be a little more complex than that.

Comment: Do the groups of three digits need to be set off by whitespace (or beginning/end of string) in order to count?

Comment: Yes. The groups of three digits need to be surrounded by white spaces , beginning and end of string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you consider the following a more elegant solution:

```
m=re.findall(r"\b\d{3}\b", "111 chgsds 123 jdswu 456 x111101 765")
```

Comment: This would not catch something like `123` inside of the string `"ab123cd"`.  I'm not sure if this should be considered a 'match' based on the OP's question...

Comment: @mattforsythe His original expression doesn't match that, and so do mine.

Comment: True, but you are also introducing matches on things like `abc 123, def`.  (Although the OP probably wants to match these anyway.)